# Which Rust RNG should be used for multithreaded sampling?

Tags: random, rust, parallel-processing, sampling, rayon

I am trying to create a function in Rust which will sample from M normal distributions N times. I have the sequential version below, which runs fine. I am trying to parallelize it using Rayon, but am encountering the error

`Rc<UnsafeCell<ReseedingRng<rand_chacha::chacha::ChaCha12Core, OsRng>>> cannot be sent between threads safely`

It seems my `rand::thread_rng` does not implement the traits `Send` and `Sync`. I tried using `StdRng` and `OsRng` which both do, to no avail because then I get errors that the variables `pred` and `rng` cannot be borrowed as mutable because they are captured in a `Fn` closure.

This is the working code below. It errors when I change the first into_iter() to into_par_iter().

```
use rand_distr::{Normal, Distribution};
use std::time::Instant;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {

    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

    (0..means.len()).into_iter().for_each(|i| {
        (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
            let normal = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
            preds[i][j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rng);
        })
    });

    preds
}

fn main() {

    let means = vec![0.0; 67000];
    let sds = vec![1.0; 67000];
    let start = Instant::now();
    let preds = rprednorm(100, means, sds);
    let duration = start.elapsed();
    
    println!("{:?}", duration);
}
```

Any advice on how to make these two iterators parallel?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at StdRng? https://docs.rs/rand/0.8.5/rand/rngs/struct.StdRng.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems my `rand::thread_rng` does not implement the traits `Send` and `Sync`.

Why are you trying to send a `thread_rng`? The entire point of `thread_rng` is that it's a *per-thread* RNG.

> then I get errors that the variables pred and rng cannot be borrowed as mutable because they are captured in a Fn closure.

Well yes, you need to Clone the StdRng (or Copy the OsRng) into each closure. As for `pred`, that can't work for a similar reason: once you parallelise the loop the compiler does not know that every `i` is distinct, so as far as it's concerned the write access to `i` could overlap (you could have two iterations running in parallel which try to write to the same place at the same time) which is illegal.

The solution is to use rayon to iterate in parallel *over the destination vector*:

```rust
fn rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {
    let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

    preds.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
        let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
        (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
            let normal = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
            e[j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rng);
        })
    });

    preds
}
```

Alternatively with `OsRng`, it's just a marker ZST, so you can refer to it as a value:

```rust
fn rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {
    let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

    preds.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
        (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
            let normal = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
            e[j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rand::rngs::OsRng);
        })
    });

    preds
}
```

`StdRng` doesn't seem very suitable to this use-case, as you'll either have to create one per toplevel iteration to get different samplings, or you'll have to initialise a base rng then clone it once per spark, and they'll all have the same sequence (as they'll share a seed).